# http to https is not working

Tags: nginx, redirection

I have done the redirection on NGINX but it still not working.

first, I need to redirect http://www.example.com to https://www2.example.com

also, redirect https://www.example.com to https://www2.example.com

I have the following conf:

```
[root@andysrv5-nginx ~]# cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;


######   setting for crm.example.com http  
     server {
        listen 80;
        server_name crm.example.com;
        access_log off;
        location / {
              proxy_pass http://172.31.16.207/;
              proxy_redirect off;
              proxy_set_header Host $host;
              proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
              proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
              client_max_body_size 10m;
              client_body_buffer_size 128k;
              proxy_connect_timeout 90;
              proxy_send_timeout 90;
              proxy_read_timeout 90;
              proxy_buffer_size 4k;
              proxy_buffers 4 32k;
              proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
              proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
                }
     }

######   setting for crm.example.com https  


    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name crm.example.com;
        server_tokens off;
        access_log off;
        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/fullchain-1657107464.pem";
        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/privkey-1657107464.pem";
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!EXPORT:!DES;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        location / {
                proxy_pass https://172.31.16.207/;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                }
          if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ )
            {
            return 405;
            }
        }


######   setting for www2.example.com http  

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com;
        return 301 https://www2.example.com$request_uri;
        }


    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www2.example.com;
        return 301 https://www2.example.com$request_uri;
        }




######   setting for www2.example.com https  ####################


    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name www.example.com;
        return 301 https://www2.example.com$request_uri;
        }


    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name www2.example.com;
        server_tokens off;
        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/www2.certificate.crt";
        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/www2.private.key";
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!EXPORT:!DES;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        location / {
                proxy_pass https://10.10.10.209/;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                }
          if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ )
            {
            return 405;
            }
        }

}
```

Could you please help with what I did wrong?!!

Comment: Is `https://www2.example.com` loading correctly?

Comment: yes, loaded correctly

Comment: Is there anything in the logs when requesting `http://www.example.com`?

Comment: I disabled access log and error log because nginx not started with them on

Comment: Enable all logging at least until you have a working configuration.

Comment: it gives the following when I enabled the log


andysrv5-nginx nginx[1630]: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
 andysrv5-nginx nginx[1630]: nginx: [emerg] open() "/usr/share/nginx/on" failed (13: Permission denied)
 andysrv5-nginx nginx[1630]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
 andysrv5-nginx systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
 andysrv5-nginx systemd[1]: Failed to start The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has failed

Comment: Do you have a configuration such as `access_log on;`?

Comment: yes,
my mistake, I changed it from off to on , for my ignorancy that it should be.

now it is ok, I will send the log

Comment: should make log level, debug?

  error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

Comment: no, nothing in the logs.

Comment: If there is nothing in the logs, perhaps `nginx` did not receive a request.

Comment: but the redirection of https://www2.example.com is working and also other domain

both servers are behind nginx

Comment: Try setting [`error_log debug;`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log).

Comment: What is the redirect that is not working? Please show the exact request you make and the response for it.

Comment: If `nginx` is receiving receiving requests with `error_log` configured for `debug`, you should be seeing at least 50 entries in the error log per request, if not hundreds per request. If you don't see this, then `nginx` is not what is processing your requests, or it is not using your current configuration.

Comment: Yes, I saw this when I enable debug, it works. I mean the nginx 

but no redirection is working, not for http://www.example.com or http://www2.example.com or https://www.example.com

all these requests should redirect to https://www2.example.com.  but not working and there is no error

Comment: this means, there is something in the configuration not making this redirection

Comment: how can I attached the output or the configuration here?

Comment: Please put the full configuration in a code block in the question.

Comment: I'm not clear what could be the problem. From a different computer, what is the output of `curl -I http://www.example.com`?

Comment: root@andysrv8-www:~# curl -I http://www.example.xom
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.20.1
Date: Thu, 25 Aug 2022 20:35:22 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 169
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://www2.example.com/

Comment: root@andysrv8-www:~# curl -I http://www2.example.com
curl: (7) Failed to connect to www2.example.com port 80: Connection refused

Comment: The output does not match the posted configuration. Something else is wrong.

Comment: I am not sure, I tried to figure out, but I couldn;t find it

Comment: The `curl` response should include `Location: https://www2.example.com/`, but it is just `Location: www2.example.com`. That doesn't match the configuration you posted.